# How to plot vertical wind barb profiles with d3-windbarbs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have vertical wind profile data, e.g. altitude (meters above gnd, wind direction and wind speed)  One profile goes from 40meters to 1200meters ..data example
# Data File Format (remainder of file): Height(m), Wind Direction, Wind Speed(m/s)
584
40.1007, 198.0468, 5.4182
41.9659, 198.2216, 5.4562
43.831, 198.3939, 5.4942
where 584 is number of rows of data. Data files are created in 10 minute intervals,so 144 files/profiles per day.. I am working with d3.js and the windbarb/arrow software. But can't get the windbarbs to display vertically. notice the image included. Everything, seems to work except proper vertical placement of the windbarbs. My software is included

```
 <svg width="800" height="400">
 <g transform="translate(150, 20)"></g>
 </svg>

 let plt_data = [];
 var myData = [  
 [40,35], 
 [10,120], 
 [20,245], 
 [60,90], 
 [30,185]
 ];

 d3.select('svg')
 .selectAll('g')     
 .data( myData)
 .join('g')  
 .attr('height', function(d,i){
 return i*3;
 })   
 .attr('x', function(d, i) { 
 plt_data[i] = new WindArrow(myData[i][0],myData[i][1],'svg g',40);     
 })
 .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i*50; });

[enter image description here][1]


/**** BELOW is the d3windarrow.js file ***/
/* Creates a wind arrow for display in station model */
/* The default size of the arrow is: width = 8, height = 2.
The size is then given by the @arrowWidth parameter.
The canvas is a square of 2*arroWidth.
The arrow is drawn in the center of the square and rotated to the 
corresponding angle (@direction).
*/
class WindArrow {

 constructor (speed, direction, container, arrowWidth) {
    'use strict';
    var index = 0,
        i;

    this.speed = speed;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.trigDirection = direction + 90;
    this.scale = arrowWidth / 8;

    this.ten = 0;
    this.five = 0;
    this.fifty = 0;

    // Create the canvas
    this.main = d3.select(container)
        .append('svg:svg')
        .attr('height', 2 * arrowWidth)
        .attr('width', 2 * arrowWidth);
    this.main.append('defs').append('clipPath')
        .attr('id', 'clip')
        .append('rect')
        .attr('height', 2 * arrowWidth)
        .attr('width', 2 * arrowWidth);

    // Draw the widget area    
    this.widget = this.main
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'wind-arrow');

    if (this.speed > 0) {
        // Prepare the path
        this.path = "";
        if (this.speed <= 7) {
            // Draw a single line
            this.longBar();
            index = 1;
        } else {
            this.shortBar();
        }

        // Find the number of lines in function of the speed
        this.five = Math.floor(this.speed / 5);
        if (this.speed % 5 >= 3) {
            this.five += 1;
        }

        // Add triangles (5 * 10)
        this.fifty = Math.floor(this.five / 10);
        this.five -= this.fifty * 10;
        // Add tenLines (5 * 2)
        this.ten = Math.floor(this.five / 2);
        this.five -= this.ten * 2;

        // Draw first the triangles
        for (i = 0; i < this.fifty; i++) {
            this.addFifty(index + 2 * i);
        }
        if (this.fifty > 0) {
            index += 2 * (this.fifty - 0.5);
        }

        // Draw the long segments
        for (i = 0; i < this.ten; i++) {
            this.addTen(index + i);
        }
        index += this.ten;

        // Draw the short segments
        for (i = 0; i < this.five; i++) {
            this.addFive(index + i);
        }

        this.path += "Z";

        // Add to the widget
        this.widget.append('g')
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', this.path)
            .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + arrowWidth + ', ' + arrowWidth + ') scale(' + this.scale + ') rotate(' + this.trigDirection + ' ' + 0 + ' ' + 0 + ')  translate(-8, -2)')
            .attr('class', 'wind-arrow');

    } else {
        // No wind, draw double circles
        this.zeroWind();
    }

};

shortBar = function () {
    // Draw an horizontal short bar.
    'use strict';
    this.path += "M1 2 L8 2 ";
};
longBar = function () {
    // Draw an horizontal long bar.
    'use strict';
    this.path += "M0 2 L8 2 ";
};
addTen = function (index) {
    // Draw an oblique long segment corresponding to 10 kn.
    'use strict';
    this.path += "M" + index + " 0 L" + (index + 1) + " 2 ";
};
addFive = function (index) {
    // Draw an oblique short segment corresponding to 10 kn.
    'use strict';
    this.path += "M" + (index + 0.5) + " 1 L" + (index + 1) + " 2 ";
};
addFifty = function (index) {
    // Draw a triangle corresponding to 50 kn.
    'use strict';
    this.path += "M" + index + " 0 L" + (index + 1) + " 2 L" + index + " 2 L" + index + " 0 ";
};
zeroWind = function () {
    // Draw two circles corresponding to null wind.
    'use strict';
    var circle = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0.5)
        .outerRadius(1)
        .startAngle(-Math.PI)
        .endAngle(Math.PI);

    this.widget.append('g')[enter image description here][1]
        .attr('class', 'wind-circle')
        .append('path').attr('d', circle)
        .attr('vector-effect', 'non-scaling-stroke')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(8, 2)');
};
}
```